# how to save json data in Angular 2 in a certain format

Tags: angular

I'm using angular2-txt npm package for saving error json data to .txt file, but how to save data in following format?

```
{
  "message": "The request is invalid.",
  "modelState": {
    "userData[1].id": [
      "'id' must be greater than '0'."
    ],
    "userData[3].Endpoints[0].EmailAddress": [
      "'Email Address' should not be empty.",
      "'Email Address' must be between 1 and 250 characters. You entered 0 characters."
    ],
    "userData[7].TenantName": [
      "'Tenant Name' should not be empty."
    ],
    "userData[9].TenantId": [
      "'Tenant Id' must be greater than '0'."
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You should read the documentation of the library you're using, as it isn't directly related to Angular.

Comment: This is the json, how are you using the library to save this..  Usually in all npm packages, there's a Readme file explaining how the component is used

Comment: I am using angular2-txt npm package. This package uses class Angular2Txt() for saving data. This class has options parameter which uses various separators for the format but I am unable to use the correct one. Please suggest?